# JSforce not integrating with express in Node

Tags: express, salesforce, jsforce

To give some context, I am a front end dev tasked with intergrating salesforce into a react app. This is a new learning curve for me as I am a SF newbie. I have been looking for a way to make intergration easier and I came across a video that showed how I can use a node packaged called JSforce to auth and fetch data from SF to my node express backend. I did as the video suggested but something appears to be not working as I am not console logging anything. Can anyone who has experience in using Jsforce take a look at my code below and let me know where I have gone wrong?

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 5000;
const jsforce = require('jsforce');

    const username = 'blah';
    const password = 'blah+ security token';
    
    var conn = new jsforce.Connection({
        // you can change loginUrl to connect to sandbox or prerelease env.
        loginUrl: 'https://tahina-test2-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/'
    });
    conn.login(username, password, function(err, userInfo) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }
        // Now you can get the access token and instance URL information.
        // Save them to establish connection next time.
        console.log(conn.accessToken);
        console.log(conn.instanceUrl);
        // logged in user property
        console.log('User ID: ' + userInfo.id);
        console.log('Org ID: ' + userInfo.organizationId);
        // ...
    
        conn.sobject('Account').retrieve('0012X000022HhE5QAK', function(err, account) {
            if (err) {
                return console.error(err);
            }
            console.log('Name : ' + account.Name);
            // ...
        });
    });
    
    app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`));
```

Comment: also, whenever I type a password wrong, it console logs that. The issue is that it does fetch this record or console log anything that tells me SF is connected :/

Comment: Hey, I just tried your code, and it is working for me. Maybe double check that your instance url, username, and password (plus security token) are valid?

Comment: hey @wooters i did and its still not working :/ Would it be possible for me to have a chat with you on this on private?

Comment: Have you allowed the IP address in your org?